# Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Unable to start process. Timeout waiting for child process to open named pipes

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm having a problem on Visual Studio 2022.

> Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Unable to start process. Timeout waiting for child process to open named pipes.

Any help is much appreciated

[image]

Comment: Can you take screen shot of error? What is your git provider (e.g. GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, etc.)?

Comment: Hi @DoNhuVy, I have added the error. my git provider is Azure DevOps

Answer (score 8):

Try to run the Visual Studio application as an administrator.

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Comment: didn't work for me